# Using an InputStream for Logging and then XML parsing

Tags: java

What I want to do is log the output from an inputstream that I go using

```
org.apache.http.HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
org.apache.http.HttpResponse content =entity.getContent();


            //Print the result to the screen for debugging
            //puroposes
            if(Logging.DEBUG) {
                InputStream content =entity.getContent();

                int i;
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                while( (i=content.read()) != -1 ) {
                    b.append((char)i);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, b.toString());
            }
```

Now after I have finished logging, I want to use the exact same stream through an XML parser.  The problem is that it tells me that the steam has already been used.

I tried to the use `mark()` and `reset()` calls before and after debugging but it didn't work.

Comment: consider using TeeInputStream from apache commons library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the inputstream that is returned supports it. The default implementation in the `InputStream` class does nothing, as [described in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark%28int%29). So you can't be sure whether the returned Stream actually supports it. To be sure of this, you should wrap it in a [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html), which does supports these methods.

Comment: maybe this solution may be helpful for somebody: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2013/12/redirect-stream-to-logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

In general `mark()` and `reset()` won't work on an arbitrary InputStream.  They only work on subclasses like `FileInputStream` where the underlying data source supports these operations.

For something like a SocketInputStream or a console InputStream, your only option will be to read and buffer the entire stream contents somewhere; e.g. in memory or by writing it to a temporary file.